# How can I pass an enum from mapper to reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, enums, mapreduce, inner-classes

I was trying to pass an enum from mapper to reducer, in job conf, I set 
`job.setMapOutputValueClass(StatisticTypes.class);`

and in mapper, I passed a type of this enum, but always get

```
Type mismatch in value from map: expected StatisticTypes, recieved StatisticTypes$2
```

It seems like types of this enums were treated as a nested class of the enum
I'm wondering how can I set `mapoutputvalueclass` to include it's nested classes. Or is it possible to set multiple mapoutput classes?

Another related question
[How to set mapOutputValueClass as Enum in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369532/how-to-set-mapoutputvalueclass-as-enum-in-hadoop)

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23249886/729819

Comment: @BenWatson, I did look at that, the problem is not about how to implement writable interface for enums but the type mismatch between enum.class and types of enums.class